# How do you make the pop up appear and print a sentence in the main/side panel?

Tags: r, shiny, printing, popup

I want to make a R shiny application that prints a riddle (raadsel) and where somebody has to enter an answer (antwoord). If someone puts in the right answer, a pop up appears that says "Goed geraden...) otherwise the popup says "try again". I wrote the code underneath, but unfortunately when I put in an answer, a popup does not appear. Also, it does not print the riddle. Where does it go wrong and does somebody have a solution?

```
library(shiny)

# Definieer raadsels en antwoorden
raadsels <- c("Ik ben groot als ik jong ben, maar klein als ik oud ben. Wat ben ik?", 
              "Ik ben altijd om je heen, maar nooit gezien. Wat ben ik?")
antwoorden <- c("een boom", "lucht")

# UI voor de spiegel
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactieve Spiegel"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("antwoord", "Wat is je antwoord?"),
      actionButton("controleer", "Controleer Antwoord")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("raadsel_output"),
      verbatimTextOutput("feedback")
    )
  )
)

# Server logica
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$raadsel_output <- renderText({
    raadsels[1]  # Weergeef het eerste raadsel
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$controleer, {
    antwoord <- tolower(input$antwoord)  # Antwoorden zijn niet hoofdlettergevoelig
    
    if (antwoord %in% tolower(antwoorden)) {
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Goed Geraden!",
          "Jullie mogen de envelop openen."
        )
      )
    } else {
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Fout Antwoord",
          "Het antwoord is niet correct. Probeer het opnieuw."
        )
      )
    }
  })
}

# Run de app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It works for me, try restarting your `R` session.

Comment: Hmm, weird. When I open it in the browser it works, but not in Rstudio...